# Sorting values Bottom-Top order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list that contains certain floating values. I am trying to sort the list in bottom-top order. The only Order I am trying to implement is from Top-Bottom to Bottom-Top but what I have found so far are ascending/descending orders. How can I implement this?

```
public List<float> MyValues = new List<float>();

public void Start()
{
  MyValues.Add(3.8f);
  MyValues.Add(10.2f);
  MyValues.Add(1.4f);
}
```

How can I sort this List to Bottom-Top so that the result is:

```
1.4
10.2
3.8
```

Comment: Do you mean, you want to revese list order? What about `MyValues.Reverse()`?

Comment: Ah yes to reverse basically.

Comment: [`List<T>.Reverse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.reverse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already mentioned in the comment, you can use `MyValues.Reverse();` to flip the order of the list around.
You can find the Microsoft Documentation on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.reverse?view=net-5.0)

So in your case it would basically be

```
public List<float> MyValues = new List<float>();

public void Start()
{
  MyValues.Add(3.8f);
  MyValues.Add(10.2f);
  MyValues.Add(1.4f);
  MyValues.Reverse();
}
```

You can also sort a list before reversing it, let's say that you want to sort a list from Z-A, you can just sort it alphabetically as usual and then reverse it.